# HttpPostedFileBase всегда равен null (HttpPostedFileBase always is null) - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Ниже контроллер, получаю параметр uploadImage и делаю Update бд, но параметр всегда равен null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Model,Color,YearOfIssue,Plate,Image")] Cars cars, HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage)
    {
        if (uploadImage != null)
        {
            byte[] imageData = null;
            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
                imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
            cars.Image = imageData;
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(cars).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(cars);
    }
```

Кусок из представления Edit

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="uploadImage" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Применить" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: В чем может быть проблема? В отладчике когда выбираю файл на сайте, оно пропускает весь код условия if (uploadImage != null) и обновляет только другие данные.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить дополнительное условие

```
if (uploadImage != null && uploadImage.ContentLength > 0)
{

}
```

Comment: если используется поле для отправки файла (input type="file"), следует определить атрибут enctype как multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы файлы отправлялись из формы браузера, необходимо добавлять к тегу формы атрибут enctype со значением multipart/form-data:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="uploadImage" />
</form>
```

Подробнее про атрибут: http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/enctype

> multipart/form-data
>   Данные не кодируются. Это значение применяется при отправке файлов.

Answer (score -1):

must have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Cars", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

PROFIT!!!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Если используется поле для отправки файла (input type="file"), следует определить атрибут enctype как multipart/form-data.